# Before the big bang, what was the temperature?

Tags: history

What was the temperature of space before the Big Bang event?

Comment: This is not about space exploration, [Astronomy SE](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/) or [Physics SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/) should be a better location for getting an answer.

Comment: @user21319, See physics.SE, at: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/147612/10389

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer to this was **there was no temperature because there was no "BEFORE the big bang"**.  The big bang wasn't just the creation of all matter in the universe, it was also the creation of space-time itself.  This is a difficult concept for people new to cosmology and relativistic space-time, but the book "[A Brief History of Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Brief_History_of_Time)" by Stephen Hawking gives a relatively (no pun intended) clear explanation of this.